# Push Segues Not Working?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, segue, push

I'm pretty new to mobile development but I've been trying to code this app but am having difficulties with the segue animations.

I have a button on my home screen which segues to a Viewcontroller with a tableview embedded inside it. The cells in that tableview segue to another view with a tableview, with cells that segue to another view (etc, etc). All of these views have a navigation controller embedded within them (except for the home screen).

My problem is that although I've selected that these segues be Push/Show, all of the new views are presenting modally. Since I have the user selecting a cell from the table, I would prefer that the new views slide in from the right.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add navigation controller to the push segue.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. My view controllers already have navigation controllers embedded in them?